# Admin Panel for Headless/Decoupled CMS with SPA

Tags: javascript, angular, content-management-system, frontend, headless

Recently I was doing R&D for a new project, SPA application (in Angular) with headless CMS (hasn't yet been chosen). I'm pretty confident with my knowledge, however I'm missing one crucial point.

It is clear to me how the non technical moderator would update content in the original approach with coupled CMS.

However in headless approach the CMS serves as a backend, so how would non technical moderator update the content of that website?

Does the decoupled approach require the dev team to manually build "editor page" containing all the fields?

I was trying to find the answer but I might be lacking proper naming (tried: *headless cms admin panel*, *content management in headless cms*   etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done with the research and Q&A.
In the headless/decoupled approach it's on the developers to build the admin panel for content edition. There are some plugins that provide out of the box templating (could find a lot for Wordpress, Drupal on the other hand seemed to be very much ignored).
I will have to rethink my initial choice.

Comment: Would something like Strapi be considered to have an Admin panel?